Pushout of an surjective map is surjective
This is an exercise from Rotman , Introduction to homological algebra.
Given a pushout diagram in $R$-Mod
$$\begin{array}
AA & \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & C \\
\downarrow{f} & & \downarrow{\beta} \\
B & \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} & D  
\end{array}
$$
prove that $g$ injective implies $\alpha$ injective, and that $g$ surjective implies $\alpha$ surjective.
I have problems with the surjective part, how to solve it ?

If you can use the fact that in $R$-mod surjective morphisms are the same as epimorphisms, see this post.

You may also try to use the explicit construction of push-out.

Let $K= \{(f(a),g(a)): a\in A\}$, so that canonically $D= (B\oplus C)/K$.
Take $(b,c)$ in $D$, then assuming $g$ is surjective we have:  $$(b,c) = (b,g(a)) = (b+f(a),0) =\alpha(b+f(a))$$

ADDED: A proof without using the explicit construction of pushout.
The submodule $\text{im}(\alpha) + \text{im}(\beta)$ of $D$ also satisfies the universal property (check it), so in fact $D =\text{im}(\alpha) + \text{im}(\beta)$.
But $g$ surjective implies $\text{im}(\beta) \leq \text{im}(\alpha)$ , as $\beta(c) = \beta(f(a)) = \alpha(g(c))$, so $D= \text{im}(\alpha )$ as desired.

Thanks, I think I have it. But the correct thing would be to take $b + f(a)$, right?

Yes that's right, fixed
